# change color for one word

Tags: html

I have a paragraph with some text in it. How do I change the color of just one word w/in that paragraph? My attempt at it ends up changing the color of 'is' but also puts 'is' on it's own line.

```
<div class="myHeader">
   <h1>This is my heading</h1>
   <h2>This <div class="test">is</div> the paragraph</h2>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.myHeader {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;  
}

.test{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of having `.test` be a `div`, use something like `span`.

It's getting it's own line because `div` is a block element, while `span` and the like are inline.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.  You can either change the div to a span as esqew noted or you can change your style rule to this

```
.test{
  display:inline;
  color: red;
}
```

effectively treating the block level div as a span.

Comment: @user522962 Oh, I completely agree. :) That's why I upvoted his answer.  I feel it's the correct method, but as you said, this is just an alternative.

Answer (score -4):

What i would do for `<div class="test">is</div>` is make it `<div id=test>is</div>` then change the css to

```
#test{
color:red;
}
```

hope this helps :)